# T extends Object declared in method where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable

Tags: generics, java-8

I'm in the process of compiling my existing code in java 8 and I see this warning:

```
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Object declared in method <T>mtd1(...)
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
```

Here is the call where this warning is being displayed:

```
IExample<T> model = (IExample<T>) Utils.getModel(x.getModel());
```

and here's the getModel method:

```
public static IExample<?> getModel(Class1 model) {
        if (model instanceof IExample<?>) {
            return (IExample<?>)model;
        } else if (model instanceof Class2){
            return getModel(((Class3)model).getActualModel());
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I went through this [article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html) and implemented a helper method as follows:

```
private static <T> IExample<T> mtd1Helper (IExample<T> model) {         
        return (IExample<T>) model;
}
```

and changed the invocation to the below, but even after this it wants me to explicitly do a cast to (IExample), following which I still see a warning.

```
IExample<T> model = mtd1Helper(Utils.getModel(x.getModel()));
```

What am i missing?

Here's the relevant section of the code:

```
private static <T> void mtd1(final JTable table) {
...
IExample<T> model = (IExample<T>) Utils.getModel(table.getModel());
...
}

public static IExample<?> getModel(Class1 model) {
        if (model instanceof IExample<?>) {
            return (IExample<?>)model;
        } else if (model instanceof Class2){
            return getModel(((Class3)model).getActualModel());
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And, this is how I modified it:

```
private static <T> void mtd1(final JTable table) {
    ...
    IExample<T> model = mtd1Helper(Utils.getModel(x.getModel()));
    ...
    }

private static <T> IExample<T> mtd1Helper (IExample<T> model) {         
        return (IExample<T>) model;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are wrong since you don't put the whole code on,  but I can give you some advice. I wish it can helped you.

`List<?>` is equivalent to `List<? extends Object>`. which means you can't add anything except `null`, it is often used for **read** mode. for example:

```
List<?> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(null);//ok
list.add(new Object()); //error
```

for the **write** mode, you can using `List<? super Object>`, for example:

```
List<? super Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Object());//ok
```

but a `List<*>` can be assigned to a `List<?>`, for example:

```
List<? super Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
List<? extends Object> list2 = list; // ok
```

this why wildcard capture needs a help method, because a `List<T>` both can **read** the value of `T` and **write** a `T` value.

```
void foo(List<?> i) {
    fooHelper(i);
}

private <T> void fooHelper(List<T> l) {
    l.set(0, l.get(0));
}
```

but when you pass the `i` twice, the error occurs again, for example:

```
void foo(List<?> i) {
    fooHelper(i,i);
    //         ^--- wildcard capture error
}

private <T> void fooHelper(List<T> l,List<T> r) {
    l.set(0, r.get(0));
}
```

**Note**: which means you must operates (**read** & **write**) `List<T>` around in the `fooHelper` method, but your `mtd1Helper` just return it directly.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand why I'm seeing the warning. I understand that the getModel() method returns a wildcard IExample<?>, but when I pass this to the helper method, where I use IExample<T> as the type, shouldn't that be enough for the compiler to infer that the datatype here is a T. Why should I still need to add a @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") as well as perform an explicit cast to (IExample<T>) of the returned object be needed?

Comment: @user3723491 Hi, the documentation example don't need a `@SuppressWarning` annotation. if you want to solve the problem you need  put your whole code in the question.

Comment: I've added the whole code that's relevant to this discussion. Thanks.

Comment: @user3723491 sir, it's error not a warning: **"incompatible types: inferred type does not conform to equality constraint(s)"**. if you don't want any unchecked warning above your edited code you must do the rest of work in the `mtd1Helper` method rather then return it. that I have already said in my answer.

Comment: It's a warning and not an error I get about adding @SuppressWarning. Also, I did as you suggested and did the rest of the work in mtd1Helper, but still the same issue.

Comment: @user3723491 are you sure? but it in my machine is a capture error. could you upload your code on github?